# How can a JavaScript program know if a global property name was defined by ECMA-262?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-next, ecma

Consider a hypothetical function called `isEcmaGlobal` that returns `true` for string names of ECMA-262 globals.

```
$ node
> isEcmaGlobal('Array')
true
> isEcmaGlobal('process')
false
```

How would one design this function?

Comment: Just have it use a constant lookup table filled with the names defined in the spec?

Comment: @Bergi My answer shows why that has limited use.

Comment: I commented before I saw that it's a self-answered question. But I think that a hardcoded set of names is the only implementation of a "*function that returns `true` for string names of ECMA-262 globals.*". If you wanted to "detect whether a builtin of the current engine is defined by the standard", or "detect all standard-defined globals that the current engine implements", or something like that, those would be different questions (and I'd recommend an [edit]). And tbh, I don't understand what use any of these would have…

Comment: So here's how I view this. I'm working on a project where this question came up. I spent a couple of hours distilling the interesting information to this page. If the content I volunteered to this community is not good enough, then I am happy to move it to my own website to benefit from the traffic myself. I respect your scrutiny over the free beer, but I will leave whether it is cold enough or the right brand is up to moderator discretion, and that decision affects whether I'll volunteer here again.

Answer (score 0):

Lets be careful here. We need to ask another question before this answer will make sense: **Are we categorizing globals by what ECMA-262 ("the standard") says *now*, or by the standard governing our program's runtime?**

Put another way: Should multiple machines see the same answers?

### Going by the Current Standard

Let's say we want `isEcmaGlobal` to return `true` in terms of what the standard says *right now*. I won't show any code here because if you care about this kind of problem, then you probably already thought to download or scrape standard global names.

### Going by the Current Runtime

Now let's assume we want `isEcmaGlobal` to return `true` in terms of *offline* information available in the current runtime. It's not as easy as iterating over the "own" property names of the global object and checking them against a hard-coded array like `['Array', 'Object', ...]`. If we did that, then we'd have to verify our array is correct. We can't verify hard-coded data because it assumes `isEcmaGlobal` is already written for that exact runtime! We cannot paste in global names from ECMA-262, because we don't know if the version of that document is in parity with the runtime. We also can't check the Internet because we assumed an offline solution.

So we can't hard code, but we can try something else. I'll use Node.js v14.16.0 and its built-in `vm` module. This program exploits `vm`'s need to provide standard globals in a new evaluator. We tell `vm` to evaluate code using an empty global object, but that global object simply won't be empty.

```js
const vm = require('vm');

function isEcmaGlobal(identifier) {
  try {
    // Lol, what security?
    vm.runInContext(identifier, vm.createContext({}))
    return true;
  } catch (e) {
    return false;
  }
}
```

Couple of things here.

First, a warning: This example uses unsanitized code execution for illustration and brevity. Do not put it on your clipboard with intent to take a shortcut.

Second, you can see our goal is to create a fresh evaluator with only standard globals defined, and no visibility into what's going on outside of the evaluator (`eval` does not do either of these things). If we get that evaluator, then you can just toss `Object.getOwnPropertyNames(new Function('return this')())` into it and we all go home.

But we're making a predicate, so assuming the "lean" global object is correct, evaluation will throw a `ReferenceError` for non-standard identifiers.

Unfortunately, somehting isn't right.

```
> isEcmaGlobal('Array')
true
> isEcmaGlobal('process')
false // yes!
> isEcmaGlobal('global')
false // yes!!
> isEcmaGlobal('console')
true  // no!!!
```

Darn, we still have a Node global for some reason. So at this point you could say I'm making this all too complicated because Node.js doesn't add *that many globals*, or that I missed a configuration option or existing predicate. You'd be right on all counts, but that's missing the point of the question. The question started with "Can a *JavaScript program* know...?", and my use of Node is meant to illustrate a way to approach the problem without hard-coding standard global names and creating a contradiction. Even if Node.js added only one non-standard global, the problem remains if we can't get a clean evaluator.

### Recap

To implement `isEcmaGlobal` in *some* JavaScript runtime, that runtime needs to give you a way to run a *bare-bones* JS evaluator, free of all host-specific extensions. `eval` doesn't count. Make it such that that you only accept identifiers, and then evaluate those identifiers. Interpret an exception as reason to return `false`.

Comment: Notice your function is also broken for `hasOwnProperty` and other things that the global object inherits from `Object.prototype`